Is it safe to insert a range in std::vector if its source is at the tail of the same vector?
Is it safe to insert a range in std::vector if its source is the tail of the same vector?
I need to insert some elements to std::vector as copies of elements in the same vector which positioned later than the inserted place.
So, I wrote the following code demo :
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        v.reserve(2*v.size());

        // Works just fine on both CLang and MSVC
        v.insert(
            v.begin() + 3,
            v.begin() + 5,
            v.end()
        );

        std::cout << "insert: ";
        std::ranges::copy(v, std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, ", "});
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        auto range_to_insert = std::ranges::subrange(v.begin() + 5, v.end());

        v.reserve(v.size() + range_to_insert.size());   // To avoid reallocation and iterators invalidation during insert_range

        // If previous reservation took place, crashes address sanitizer on MSVC and gives wrong results in Debug on my local PC with the latest MSVC x64
        v.insert_range(
            v.begin() + 3,
            range_to_insert
        );

        std::cout << "insert_range: ";
        std::ranges::copy(v, std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, ", "});
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

I can’t reproduce this on godbolt, but on my local PC with the latest MSVC x64 in Debug it shows:
insert: 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
insert_range: 0, 1, 2, -572662307, -572662307, -572662307, -572662307, -572662307, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,

while in Release it shows the same result as on godbolt:
insert: 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
insert_range: 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,

In all cases address sanitized at  _Copy_memmove with long to show error log. And this crashes if and only if I use this line:
v.reserve(v.size() + range_to_insert.size());

I expected to have quite opposite behavior, and introduced it to avoid reallocation during insert_range. In case I remove this line, code works fine both in Release and Debug.
I can’t see any limitations for such insert neither for  std::vector<T,Allocator>::insert_range, nor for std::vector<T,Allocator>::insert.
The question is, are such operations safe or there is some violation? Can I insert elements, copying from the tail of the vector (which could affect iterators somehow) and can I insert elements, if indexes of inserted elements overlap with old indexes of source elements?
I do understand that some things in the question above are unrelated with ranges insert operations where both indexes and iterators involved, but I hope you get the point correctly.

rg must not overlap with the container. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

It is clearly unsafe as adding elements to std::vector might trigger memory reallocation which invalidates iterators. The only reason it sometimes works is because not always memory is reallocated

@AhmedAEK, I assume that this could be the chance, that's why I included the links to the documentation and tagged with language-lawyer. I just can't see such a requirement in the documentation. Do I miss something?

@ALX23z, it might not and this is why I use reserve. Slightly changed the code to have it for insert, as well. As I stated in the question, I get quite opposite behaviour.

Requirements stated in C++ standard section 24.2.4 Sequence containers [sequence.reqmts], paragraph 37: "[…]  Neither i nor j are iterators into a". with i and j being the iterator arguments to insert and a being the sequence container

Also, if v.reserve has any effect, it will invalidate the iterators in the subrange.

@Homer512, thank you. It hurts. :) Is there any way to find this information on en.cppreference.com at the std::vector<T,Allocator>::insert_range and std::vector<T,Allocator>::insert or such details in standard only? I looked over all requirements pages like CopyInsertable, but failed to find.

@BoP, thank you so much! It seems that this is exactly what happens. Missed this point.

@DamirTenishev in the cppreference site to insert that you linked yourself, it reads "first, last - the range of elements to insert, cannot be iterators into container for which insert is called" (emphasis mine)

@Homer512, thank you! I looked into the requirements and comments, never expected to see this in parameters, although, I definitely, should have. Thanks a lot, again.

@DamirTenishev    The sentence "rg must not overlap with the container"  quoted by Ahmed (which is in the link you referred to) is (one way of stating) a requirement.      The immediately following sentence "Otherwise, the behavior is undefined." is a consequence of not meeting that requirement.    [Admittedly, cppreference paraphrases the relevant standard a lot in the interests of readability but - if you wade through the relevant standard documents (both draft standards since N4950 and corresponding ratified standards) - the conclusion is currently the same].

@AhmedAEK, now with help with many others, I see. Thank you. :)

@Peter, as I answered to Homer512 above, now I can see it, thank you. Somehow I missed it while read for the first time. I should be more careful.
